# Files.write() : appending new lines in a text file

Tags: java, java-8

I'm using the code below to write into a text file

```
String content = "I Love Java";
Files.write(Paths.get(gg), (content + "\n").getBytes(UTF_8),StandardOpenOption.CREATE,StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

After 3 times of run, the text is saved into the the text as :

```
I Love JavaI Love JavaI Love Java
```

But, I want the text in the text file looks like:

```
I Love Java 
I Love Java
I Love Java
```

Any help please ?

Comment: Windows? `\r\n`. Of, even better, use other [`Files.write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.charset.Charset-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) that specifically writes lines to a file.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should avoid specific new line separators such as `"\n"` or  `"\r\n"` that depends on the OS and favor the use of the `System.lineSeparator()` constant that applies at runtime the separator of the OS on which the JVM runs.

Comment: `Files.write(Paths.get(gg), (content + System.lineSeparator()).getBytes(UTF_8),StandardOpenOption.CREATE,StandardOpenOption.APPEND);`