# Java 8: Unable to append new lines that show up in notepad

Tags: java, character-encoding, notepad

I'm appending data to a text file using java in unix openjdk version 1.8.0_151 using the Files.write() method.

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789470/files-write-appending-new-lines-in-a-text-file) which advised me to use `System.lineSeparator()` instead of `"\n"`.

My code looks like this:

```
try {
    Files.write(Paths.get("spillInfo.txt"), 
    (infoString + System.lineSeparator()).getBytes(), 
     StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

} catch (IOException e) {
     System.err.println("Caught IOException: " +  e.getMessage());
}
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769311/how-windows-notepad-interpret-characters) Notepad uses the ANSI charset and from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556104/read-and-write-text-in-ansi-format) that charset in java is `"cp1252"` but when I add `"cp1252"` or `"windows-1252"` as the arugment of `getBytes()` (or if I leave it empty like in the code above) the new lines do not show up in notepad (they do show up in notepad++ on all three counts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your Java program on Unix, System.lineSeparator() is `\n` anyway.

If you need to have Windows Notepad to have windows line separator, then use `\r\n`.

It is old thing in Windows Notepad - it recognizes only Windows `\r\n`. 
Nobody in Microsoft cares about it (and never did) :-)

Something else you can do is to introduce your own system variable and pass it to your Java program, like

```
-Dtarget_system=Windows     // or Unix
```

then in the code you can use proper line separator based on value of

```
System.getProperty("target_system")
```

Comment: Solution worked and I got a great tip about system variables. 10/10 thank you very much.